# Background video not filling screen properly

Tags: css, html, html5-video, fullscreen

I am trying to create a series of full width, full height HTML5 video backgrounds that move with the page. You can see here: http://pitfarmtennis.co.uk/cms/coaching/ (I want the first to be fixed as it is).

But the backgrounds on desktop sized screens don't fill the width, and in small screens there is an annoying empty gap to the right of the page if you scroll.

I tried to reproduce error, didn't quite work, but you can see the relevant code here, otherwise refer to previous URL: https://jsfiddle.net/beechboy707/1Lmo5dqb/

Here is the key code:

```
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
min-width: 100%;
z-index: -200;
-webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -100;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    background: url(polina.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
```

this link may be useful:
http://thenewcode.com/777/Create-Fullscreen-HTML5-Page-Background-Video

demo: http://thenewcode.com/samples/polina.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Milad Nouri - slight modification of that works perfect for my non-position fixed needs:

```
position: fixed;/*From absolute*/
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
min-width: 100%;
z-index: -100;
-webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

With hide overflow set on the container.